# APNS Certificates for new Device Token iOS

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I was working for parse push notification for iOS devices, everything was working fine, un till the device token ID changed (maybe through re-installing the app). May  anyone guide what steps need to be taken under this condition to again make my app start working.

Comment: you need to register your device token

Comment: can you be more specific, is there an explicit way to register for a given device token apart from calling 'didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken'?

Comment: show ur code....

Comment: [application registerForRemoteNotifications]; // in didFinishLaunching with options, 
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
}, also parse sever logs show: ERR! parse-server-push-adapter APNS cannot find vaild connection for <device tokenID>

Answer (score 0):

The device token can change at any time for any reason that iOS deems appropriate. Every launch of your app should check for the token and re-register if it has changed from the previous launch.

Comment: Verbose logs in parse server shows: ERR! parse-server-push-adapter APNS cannot find vaild connection for <device token ID>, do i need to re create all the APNS certificates>

Comment: No, you do not need to recreate certificates just because your device token changed. Are you certain Parse is pushing to your new token?

Comment: I am not sure as the logs say 'APNS cannot find valid connection for <device token ID>' therefore i am certain that token id is registered but server fails to send the notification